# copy certain rows in a new matrix within a loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I'm trying to split a matrix in smaller matrices depending on one characteristic (i use 'if').

```
   for jj = 1:length(FailureHoopUP_sorted)
    if FailureHoopUP_sorted(jj,1)==20
        FailureHoopUP_20(jj,:) = FailureHoopUP_sorted(jj,:);
    elseif FailureHoopUP_sorted(jj,1)==30
        FailureHoopUP_30(jj,:) = FailureHoopUP_sorted(jj,:);
    else
        FailureHoopUP_40(jj,:) = FailureHoopUP_sorted(jj,:);
    end
   end
```

The problem I have is that there are rows of zeroes that get in between the rows with data in the new created matrices.
I was wondering how i could avoid this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop, you can use logical indexing. For example:

```
FailureHoopUP_20=FailureHoopUP_sorted(FailureHoopUP_sorted(:,1)==20,:)
...
...
```

This should also solve the zeros issue (that happens because you keep the original index `jj` that is related to the length of `FailureHoopUP_sorted`).